# NameError: uninitialized constant CreatesPointOfInterest Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I am following the book Rails 5 Test Prescriptions and I am having an issue running one of the examples. Thanks for any help.

I do have a model named point_of_interest.rb
app/models/point_of_interest.rb

I get the following error:

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant CreatesPointOfInterest
```

**spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest.rb**

```
class CreatesPointOfInterest
  attr_accessor :name, :point_of_interest

  def initialize(name: "")
   @name = name
  end

  def build
   self.point_of_interest = PointOfInterest.new(name: name)
  end
end
```

**spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest_spec.rb**

```
 require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe CreatesPointOfInterest do
 describe "initialization" do
   it "creates a point of interest given a name" do
     creator = CreatesPointOfInterest.new(name: "Pyramids of Giza")
     creator.build
     expect(creator.point_of_interest.name).to eq("Pyramids of Giza")
   end
 end
end
```

**The terminal output:**

~/Desktop/adventure/adventure[development|!SP]$ rspec

```
An error occurred while loading 
./spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  RSpec.describe CreatesPointOfInterest do

   describe "initialization" do
        it "creates a point of interest given a name" do
            creator = CreatesPointOfInterest.new(name: "Pyramids of 
            Giza")
            creator.build
            expect(creator.point_of_interest.name).to eq("Pyramids of 
           Giza")
         end
   end


 NameError:
   uninitialized constant CreatesPointOfInterest
```

**Other Errors:**

```
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap- 
    1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in 
   `block in load_missing_constant'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap- 
    1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in 
    `without_bootsnap_cache'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap- 
    1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in 
    `rescue in load_missing_constant'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap- 
    1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:43:in 
    `load_missing_constant'
    ./spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest_spec.rb:3:in `<main>'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap- 
   1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in 

 --- Caused by: ---
  NameError:  uninitialized constant CreatesPointOfInterest
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes used by your app should be in the `app/` directory not `spec`

So you should have:

```
app/workflows/creates_point_of_interest.rb
```

not

```
spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest.rb
```

Your spec filename should match the class name. Are you sure this is correct?

```
spec/workflows/create_point_of_interest_spec.rb
```

but it should be

```
spec/workflows/creates_point_of_interest_spec.rb
```

Comment: I did forget the s, and that is just what the tutorial in the book had me create because they are specifications for Rspec testing.